# The server localhost:3000 at Application requires a username and password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I'm developing a Rails 3 app on Ubuntu 11.04, and I get the following browser dialog box when I try to perform an ajax post request.

> The server localhost:3000 at Application requires a username and password

All the other pages load fine. It just happens when an ajax call is performed. I'm using Mongrel for the rails development server.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue so the dialog box won't appear?

Comment: Do you have an authentication system in place? Is there anything in application.rb that might be causing your app to act like this? Is this perhaps an ajax callback that's being fired from _application.js_ or some _js.erb_ file?

Comment: Yea, I'm using Devise but the user has already been authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was caused by a security patch introduced in rails 3.0.4. ([More info here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails))

All I needed to do was **bundle update jquery-rails** and then run **rails generate jquery:install**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using the Devise gem to redirect an unauthenticated user to a login action.

This problem was reported only from some Internet Explorer users. I believe IE tries to treat authentication automatically showing a dialog box.

The solution was to ask the users to access the login url instead of the application url.

For example, instead of accessing the url http://www.myapp.com/, ask the user to access the url http://www.myapp.com/login.

Let me know if it helped!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my case since the user has already logged in.